# PHP SOAP request that needs HTTP authentication first

Tags: php, authentication, soap

I'n new to SOAP and need to make a request to https://service.printapi.de/interface/data.asmx?wsdl. When you open that page you need to provide a username and password, afterwards you are presented with the expected XML. At first I thought I needed to pass username/password as parameters with my SOAP request, but it turns out I need to seperate the authentication from the SOAP part. So how should this be done? If I understand correctly the page I am connecting to uses HTTP authentication. I have a valid username and password, but I'm not sure how to submit those to the page that I will send my SOAP request to. Should I use CURL for this?